# Android Memory Leak Bitmap

Tags: android, memory-leaks, bitmap

I am getting OutOfMemory error after continuing with my game more than 8 times, as the heap gradually fills. Upon using MAT to analyse my game's heap, came to know of below 2 causes:

1) One instance of "android.graphics.Bitmap" loaded by "" occupies 6,554,944 (35.34%) bytes. The memory is accumulated in one instance of "byte[]" loaded by "".[image]

Keywords
android.graphics.Bitmap
byte[]

2) The class "android.content.res.Resources", loaded by "", occupies 6,446,248 (34.76%) bytes. The memory is accumulated in one instance of "java.lang.Object[]" loaded by "".[image]

Keywords
java.lang.Object[]
android.content.res.Resources

Please suggest a resolution

Comment: Do your image already suitable for each screen size? Like mdpi, hdpi? Or are you using a single - huge image for all screen?

Comment: @BlazeTama Quick one.. Thanks. I just have 720p images in hdpi folder for 3 activity screens, that I display using <ImageView> I do unbind them onDestroy(). For images used in game, I call them directly as R.drawable.* in my renderer

Answer (score 0):

Try to recycle the image, example :

```
if(image!= null) {
    ((BitmapDrawable)image.getDrawable()).getBitmap().recycle(); //here
    image= (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image);
    image.setImageResource(yourresource);
}
else {
    image= (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image);
    imageView.setImageResource(yourresource);
}
```

Comment: I will try this and get back to you. Is there any possibility for byte[] buffer direct allocation like below to retain space' ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(4 * this.s.size());
      bb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
      this.vertexBuffer =bb.asFloatBuffer();'If yes, how do I free those?

Comment: @David Sorry, i dont know about the buffer

Comment: I did try your solution. I did seem to work, but still I get the same error now after some more times of continuing the game (your solution has delayed it). I guess the other cause (cause 2) should also be fixed to permanently resolve this. Any idea how??

Comment: Sorry i dont have any idea..maybe you should create a new question, to ask about the buffer? My problem was solved by just using recycle(), and unfortunately i dont understand about the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

For heavy usage of bitmaps in games (like imageButtons and the like), make sure that you're not keeping your activities alive.

1. You can play the load/unload game in onPause/onResume  with setImageDrawable(null) for every big item. You then have to set the drawables back in the views with each resume. This is great if you don't do #3.
2. Use fragments is possible, which solved the problem in that they unload the views when you destroy them.
3. If you have to have activities, you can use finish() right after your startActivity(myIntent). You'll most likely need to override the backbutton in this case to take control of the navigation since the activity you left is no longer on the back stack.

As for the ressources themselves, you'll read a lot of stuff about drawable-nodpi, but if you have a mix of programmed layouts and xml layouts adjustements, you'll want to make sure you have assets in all the drawable-?dpi folders which makes a HUGE difference for imageButtons.

Also, don't use setmaxheight in code, use the layoutparams height. That killed memory for me more than once on imageButtons.

And if you are loading pngs into views in your code, use Glide or Picasso and save yourself a world of hurt :)